# Any good documentation for SchemaExport#execute() ?

Tags: hibernate

This is crazy but in all documentation I looked at, no explanation is written.

All you can find in the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html#execute%28boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) is:

> public void execute(boolean script,
>                       boolean export,
>                       boolean justDrop,
>                       boolean justCreate)

Maybe someone can document it here or share a link to a blog?

Comment: There's a bit more documentation that I wrote in my personal wiki page: **Don't touch it with a barge pole** - in big block red letters.

Comment: @Augusto It actually can be quite useful...  in particular, I use it for setting up in-memory databases for use in unit testing.  However, I would *never* run it on a production database!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- script: if true, output the required SQL to the console.
- export: if true, actually *execute* the SQL to the configured data source.
- justDrop: if true, only output/execute SQL required to delete data structures.
- justCreate: if true, only output/execute SQL required to create data structures.