# Create list table automatic using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Is there any way to create single tale using hibernate. I have use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` but it impacts to full aplication which I don't want. Table which I want to create is basicaly use to handle list mapping between two objects, so there is no any POJO for this table.

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name="LIST_TABLE", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="EMP_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PHONE_ID")})
```

Where Employee have more then one Phone numbers.Can I create `LIST_TABLE` as `Employee` and `Phone_number` tables are already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have part of the database schema created, you don't want `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`, because as you have discovered that will try to create everything. There is another value, `hibernate.hbm2ddl.update`, but it's [not recommended for production use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221379/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-update-in-production).

Instead, I would recommend using the [SchemaExport](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html) tool to output the required SQL, extract the relevant `CREATE` and `ALTER` statements for your new table, and  run them manually.  There's a related question on how to use SchemaExport [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341922/any-good-documentation-for-schemaexportexecute/15342114#15342114).

Comment: That is correct. However, if I understood right Navnath has created his tables manually (maybe it is a legacy database) and subsequently mapped it with Hibernate. Is that right?

If that is the case "hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" should be a good option.

Comment: Yori... Really thanks for your comment..... This is what I am expecting.... Thankis Sharakan too...